# How to update a property in a .properties file without removing the comments(in Java)

Tags: java, properties

I am trying to update a property in a properties file. Its working fine but the comments which I have given in the properties file gets deleted. Comments section is very important for that properties file since many users will use that properties file and make changes to it. Below is the code I am using to store/update the property.

```
prop.setProperty("someproperty", "sometext");
prop.store(new FileOutputStream("Test.properties"), null);
```

Thank you.

Comment: You can read the entire content in to a StringBuilder and then manipulate the content and save it back to the file.

Comment: You can also have a look at the commons-configuration library for updating properties file https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/userguide/howto_properties.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't without writing entirely custom code for both load and store. Otherwise you will lose not only the comments but the ordering.

Comment: ...and here I was hoping that would have changed since I last had to do it (more than a decade ago). Ah, well...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder How could it ever change? `Properties` extends `Hashtable`, which is (a) unordered, and (b) has no provision for storing comments. Even if it did, it couldn't know where to put them, because of (a).

Comment: By adding a new, modern class to handle properties files.